# Qual é o limite máximo do PHP/MySQL/Nginx numa requisição antes da dar erro 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

E se possível como posso prolongar esse tempo para queries/requisições grandes?

Comment: O erro 504 tem mais a ver com o servidor HTTP ou com o proxy reverso (Nginx, por exemplo). Poderia por favor detalhar quais são esses servidores ou proxies?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Aparece o nginx também

Comment: Sendo fastcgi, acredito que possa sim ser um timeout excedido na requisição ao script php, mas é como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez disse é mais uma questão do servidor nginx . Poste o nginx.conf, ficará mais fácil detectar o problema

Comment: Acredito que seja no Nginx, pois o parâmetro `max_execution_time` afeta apenas a execução do script, não sendo contabilizado o tempo gasto fora do script (chamadas ao banco, etc). Pelo menos é o que a documentação diz... http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver o problema, alterei o `max_execution_time` para `900` que é equivalente a 15 minutos e deu certo!

Comment: 1 hora pra uma requisição? #medo

Comment: Sua resposta foi parar automaticamente na fila de análise como possível baixa qualidade por causa do tamanho e conteúdo. Eu escolhi o "Parece OK", mas seria legal você elaborar um pouco mais para evitar este tipo de incômodo. Também gostaria de deixar claro que não foi eu quem votou negativo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, você tem razão... mas ainda não entendi o `-1` que deram, a resposta está certa. (são pessoas como esse cara que faz o site perder a qualidade)

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Difícil entender mesmo. Pega o meu +1 para anular o -1 então.

Comment: Eu que dei o -1, a resposta em si está certa, mas não vejo justificativa para um tempo de requisição tão absurdo quanto 1 hora. Existe alguma possibilidade de alguma requisição levar um tempo tão grande de processamento? Caso sim te recomendo rever o código pois uma query tão grande assim chega a ser insustentável.

Comment: Reiterando q o -1 foi pelo valor adotado, e não pela resposta em si.

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim, concordo que talvez o tempo de uma hora pode ter sido desnecessário mas acredito que 15 minutos seria o suficiente para queries mais grandes, mas na resposta só descrevi o que eu fiz.. Alterarei lá.

Comment: Tudo bem, só pra lembrar q nem sempre uma resposta correta significa uma resposta eficiente. ela pode responder a questão porém pode trazer outros erros no futuro, isso faz uma resposta correta, porém de baixa qualidade. Vou tirar meu -1 e colocar um +1

Comment: fastcgi ou uwscgi? Se for fastcgi, talvez usar o `fastcgi_read_timeout` poderia ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17511476/1518921